# Swift: The method which belongs to nothing

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Now I am reading the famous library "RxSwift", but I have a question.

See [this page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/Map.swift).

As you know the method `_map<Element, R>(source: Observable<Element>, transform: @escaping (Element) throws -> R)` doesn't belong to any class or extension or something like that.

How is this explained?

I know the concept of "top-level", but this is different with it.

Could you explain?

Comment: _this is different with it._ Why do you think so? It's just a top-level function.

Comment: Oh, really?  I assume the  top-level concept applies to the class which has @UIApplicationMain in case of iOS. Can we write top-level functions anywhere?

Comment: Then you have your own _top-level_ concept where usual Swift community does not use the term for. I'm open to hear what is the basis of your own concept.

Comment: _Can we write top-level functions anywhere?_ Of course, yes. You can try and confirm it in many ways.

Comment: Could you see https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7?   They say  "top-level code isn’t allowed in most of your app’s source files". So, I think normally we can't use top-level functions usually.  However, is this my misunderstanding?

Comment: It says _top-level code_ which means non-declaration statements, like `println("Hello world")` (now it's `print("Hello world")`). So, it's your misunderstanding.

Comment: In languages which allow nested declaration scopes like Swift, _top-level_ usually means **_not enclosed in other declaration scopes_**. Your apps may have many top-level class (or struct or enum) definitions, top-level variable (or constant) declarations. If you took the meaning of _code_ broad, they also should be _codes_ but allowed. Function definitions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such a function is called a "global function" although in this specific case the function is only available in the RxSwift module, not globally. "Top level function" would work just as well as a descriptor.

The notion tends to throw off Java developers who are required to put every function in a class, but that requirement is an artificial and arbitrary one that only applies to Java AFAIK...

Comment: See  https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7?  They say "top-level code isn’t allowed in most of your app’s source files".  What does it mean if we can global functions anywhere?

Comment: Top level *executable* code isn't allowed. You can *define* a global function, but you can't actually call a function in a global context.